# Remove mystery alarm from Android 5

Tags: 5.1-lollipop, alarm

I'm using a lender Android 5 phone. Apparently it's default settings were set to update over WIFI only. I do have an alarm program I explicitly installed however it is clearly not the cause of the alarms at 8AM "Get to Work" which only started happening this week. There is an analog alarm clock icon at the top (without sliding down) though no actual notification to click or hint to what is triggering this mystery alarm clock. At best I could take a screenshot in nearly 24 hours from now. If there is a list of recently updated programs then I am not aware of it.

How do I remove the mystery alarm program or setting from an Android 5 phone?

Comment: Install [this app](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.evanhe.nhfree) and check which app is causing it

Comment: @beeshyams There was an accessibility option that ended up killing the Back, Home and Task Switch buttons on the phone until I disabled it. The alarm likely won't happen again until Monday. If this helps I'll let you know, you can post it as an answer and I'll happily accept it then. Thank you nonetheless for the recommendation.

Answer (score 0):

Clock, the native clock program was causing it. I can only guess that some developer somewhere decided that it should automatically start creating alarms for people. What about people who work incompatible hours? If anyone else encountered this please let me know. I had to go to the programs list, click `Clock` and disable the alarm.